# SQL Server 2005 -- Login issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-7, windows-authentication

I recently installed SQL Server 2005 on my laptop. When I run as administrator (right click -> run as administrator) I am able to log in (to sql server management studio); but when I directly try to login I'm getting error code 18456 (state 11), even though I'm the administrator.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: [Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11 Valid login but server access failure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/2733ee3e-b2a8-4397-b3e5-4f856852b450/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when run sql management studio as administrator it will run,but when you ran as your account you can not log in, when you log in as administrator you go to security -> Logins and then add your account to users and give it roll as sysadmin i try this and its work fine.

Comment: Yes, it is so. Thanks for the help (now I'm able to logon :-)). But why? Even though I'm the admin why do I need to run as admin to create user (for the first time)?

Comment: in window xp and windows server 2003 you already can log on with your account but with windows 7 this feature is gone maybe for more security